# Escaping char in filename for php script

Tags: php, html, image

I have a php script which takes in .pdf documents and creates thumbnail images of them, and it works 95% of the time, but there are a few documents I have that were giving it some trouble. I noticed that each of the documents that wasn't working had parentheses in the filename, so I went onto the server and escaped the parentheses with a backslash. That worked for one of the documents, but there are still a few that won't work...After renaming a file on the server to something arbitrary without parentheses it works fine, but that isn't a solution I can use permanently.

```
HearingAidReimbursement_\(K65\).pdf
```

is a file that works just fine when accessed like this...

```
<img src="http://144.42.108.203/thumbnails.php?pdf=HearingAidReimbursement_(K65).pdf&size=300">
```

But if I try to access

```
MemberDentalClaimForm_5738\(114\).pdf
```

like this....

```
<img src="http://144.42.108.203/thumbnails.php?pdf=MemberDentalClaimForm_5738(114).pdf&size=300">
```

no image is created...

I've tried multiple combinations of escaping in the file name and in the HTML but nothing seems to work. Here is my php in case that would help -

```
<?php
    function thumbPdf($pdf, $width){

        try{
            $tmp = 'Desktop';
            $format = "jpg";
            $source = $pdf.'[0]';
            $dest = "$tmp/$pdf.$format";

            if (!file_exists($dest)){
                $exec = "convert -scale $width $source $dest";
                exec($exec);
            }

            $im = new Imagick($dest);
            header("Content-Type:".$im->getFormat());
            echo $im;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } 

    $file = $_GET['pdf'];
    $size = $_GET['size'];
    if ($file && $size){
        thumbPdf($file, $size);
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not rename the files with parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

What about urlencoding the parentheses?

```
open paren: %28
close paren: %29
```

eg:

```
http://144.42.108.203/thumbnails.php?pdf=MemberDentalClaimForm_5738%28114%29.pdf&size=300
```

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php